# Proper way of binding an event of scroll in jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-on

I have a simple piece of code and I am struggling to figure out why my scroll event isn't getting bound. [This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JiEol) is a codepen link and I will post the code here too:

HTML:

```
<div class="aaa"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.xxx
{
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:100px;
}
```

Javascript (jquery included):

```
$("*").on("scroll", function (event)
{
    alert("scrolled!");
    console.log("scroll");
});

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".aaa").html('<div class="xxx">this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/></div>');     
});
```

What I want to do is to fire any scroll event (well, specifically the scroll in div.xxx) however if I make it so the code is loaded dynamically, it is not working.

P.S. I tried using live too, but apparently it is outdated and doesn't even support live. So I am out of choices.

**P.S. I updated my codepen example to show that `click` event works, while scroll one doesn't even though they are written in the same way.**

Comment: Click works because it's assigned to every element, and the click event bubbles through every element from the innermost (div.xxx) until the body (through div.aaa). But scroll on the other hand is only dispatched on div.xxx which is actually scrolled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you assign the listener at the start of the application, and the listener assignments run once, and are assigned to every element they find and that's it.

Only after this phase you actually add your div, that is not listened to.

The solution is to add the listener after you add your new content.

To do this you should use something similar to the following javascript

```
// declare a listener method, don't assign it yet to any element
var scrolled = function (event) {
  // just a nicer way of notification (instead of alert)
  var s = $('.scroll');
  s.fadeIn(500, function(){
    s.fadeOut(200);
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {   
    // element used to notify the user of scroll
    $('body').append('<div class="scroll" style="display: none">scrolled</div>');
    $(".aaa").html('<div class="xxx">this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/>this<br/></div>')
             .children('.xxx') // select the newly added container
             .on("scroll", scrolled); // add the method above as a scroll listener
});
```

This way you add the scroll listener every time you add fresh content. So the new divs will be listened to.

**[Working example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lfrkC)**

Comment: Yes I just realized that .on, (being a change to .live) is WAY worse event catcher. Unless I am mistaken with what .live was changed with, .on is not doing what I would expect. The thing is I want the events to work any time on any dynamically loaded code. However I am forced to bind while .live was doing it anytime without any additional binding. However, now I understand that even click wasn't working in my example!!! I just checked what classes participated in that click event and .xxx wasn't there. A valuable lesson not to trust the code you write, hehe.

Comment: So, my question again would be: has .on replaced .live removing some of it's functionality OR .live was replaced with something else and I was just mistaken into using .on as a replacement for it?

Comment: `on` is not a direct replacement for `live`. But you can use `on` to listen to delegated events. Which is similar to the mechanism behind `live`.

Comment: **IMPORTANT**: You cannot use delegated event handling for `scroll` because it does not bubble, meaning that you can only catch it on the div the scroll actually happened on. (I'd suggest you study carefully http://api.jquery.com/on/ :) - this is written there). + Though I didn't test it, my guess would be that the deprecated `live` wouldn't work either because of this bubbling issue.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
div.xxx
{
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:100px;
}
```

to:

```
div.aaa
{
    height:100px;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:100px;
}
```

There is no div with class `xxx`

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HfbwJ/1/)**